# Change UUID, Major, Minor value of beacon

Tags: ios, swift

Is there anyway to change these values using apples library?

I see that you can using estimotesdk but I'd like to do not using their sdk

Comment: It depends if the Beacon you use can be modified or not. What kind of iBeacon are you using? Anyway, you should have to go through Bluetooth Low-Energy and changes the characteristcs values.

Comment: @Larme I am using EstimoteBeacons, but ideally I would want to be able to do it for any beacon. For now though, how would I do this for the estimote beacons without using their SDK?

Comment: Anyone can do anything to set their properties of their iBeacons (in my company, we do them ourselfve) So there is no "universal" answer. For Estimote, I don't know, I don't have one.

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla Did you found a way to change the values of beacon through bluetooth peripheral  characeteristics or any other way? I also want make an app like beaconSet and LightBlue App which changes the beacon values.

Comment: @Arpit Depends what beacons you're using. I was using the estimote beacons so I ended up using their SDK as I never found a way to do it without it. I assume apps like beaconSet have SDK for all the types and they identify and use the right one on the fly.